# XAMPP on Ubuntu: Different PHP versions

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

UPDATE 16.03.2017:

I checked the log and found the following error:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320151012. The Zend Engine API version 320160303 which is installed, is newer. Contact Derick Rethans at xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug
```

I understand that I need to compile xdebug using another PHP header but how do I compile this with PHP7? Also, I am already using the latest xdebug version, which is 2.5.1

I installed xdebug on ElementaryOS together with XAMPP (PHP7) and PHPStorm.
When I enter "php -v" in the terminal, I get the following output

```
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

In addition, "php --ini" writes:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
                                   /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
```

But when running "phpinfo()" in the browser (hosted by XAMPP) the output does not contain "xdebug" and the php installation seems to be another:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path     /opt/lampp/etc
Loaded Configuration File             /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
```

In both php.ini files, I added the following but still no luck:

```
;[XDebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I checked that xdebug.so exists at this path. It has the following authorizations:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1225696 Mär 14  2016 /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
```

I have no clue what to try next - maybe someone could give me a hint!

Cheers!

Comment: After you added xdebug to the version of php running in xampp, did you restart the web server?

Comment: Yes, I did by using the XAMPP manager.

Comment: Are there any errors in the php log from XAMPP ?

Comment: Yes, error_log containes the following: Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 320151012.
The Zend Engine API version 320160303 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.
I understand that I need to compile xdebug using another PHP header but how do I compile this with PHP7?

Comment: Or is there a new version of XDebug available for you to download?

Comment: What PHP version is used by Apache? But in any case -- you better use xdebug 2.5.0 or newer.

Comment: Well, I installed version Xdebug 2.5.1. Is there a newer one available?